# UDACITY Sunshine Android App Error - java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, json

Im a beginner in Android Development and i have been following the SUNSHINE App. Everything seemed to be going great until today that I ran the App and found an Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException:http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7

I did my research and it appears The Openweathermap api now requires an API key.
As a beginner I do not know how to implement this to my current app so as I can continue with my course. I'm simply STUCK because of this.and I would appreciate any work through/help to overcome this:**(THANK YOU)**

Here is my **ForecastFragment.java**:

```js
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh){
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("94043");

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,          
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String[] data = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tommorow-Foggy-70/40",
                "weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65",
                "Fri - Heavy Rains - 65/56",
                "Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSATION - 60/51",
                "Sun - Sunny - 80/68"

        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

        mForecastAdapter =                          
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),                                                                     R.layout.list_item_forcast,        
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,      
                        weekForecast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
                R.id.listView_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

 public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

            private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();
            private  String getReadableDateString(long time){
                Date date = new Date(time*1000);
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E,MMM d");
                return format.format(date).toString();
            }
            private String formatHighLows(double high,double low){
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);
            return null;
        }



     private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
             throws JSONException{
         final String OWM_LIST = "list";
         final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
         final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
         final String OWM_MAX = "max";
         final String OWM_MIN = "min";
         final String OWM_DATETIME = "dt";
         final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

         JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
         JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

         String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
         for (int i=0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++){

             String day;
             String description;
             String highAndLow;

             JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

             long dateTime = dayForecast.getLong(OWM_DATETIME);
             day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

             JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
             description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

             JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
             double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
             double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

             highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
             resultStrs[i] = day +"-"+description +"-"+ highAndLow;
         }
         for (String s : resultStrs){
             Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Forecast entry"+s);
         }
         return resultStrs;
     }


            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(String... params){
                if (params.length == 0){
                    return null;
                }
                      HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;

      
                String forecastJsonStr = null;

                String format = "json";
                String units = "metric";
                int numDays = 7;

                try {
                    // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                    // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                    // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                    final  String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                    final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                    final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                    final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                    final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

                    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                            .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                            .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM,format)
                            .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                            .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                            .build();

                    URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Built URI" + builtUri.toString());

                    // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    // Read the input stream into a String
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    if (inputStream == null) {
                        // Nothing to do.
                        forecastJsonStr = null;
                    }
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                        // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                        // buffer for debugging.
                        buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                        // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                        forecastJsonStr = null;
                    }
                    forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                    // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                    // to parse it.
                    forecastJsonStr = null;
                } finally{
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                    if (reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (final IOException e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                        }
                    }
                }

                try {
                    return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
         if (result !=null){
             mForecastAdapter.clear();
             for (String dayForecastStr : result){
                 mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
             }
            
         }

     }
 }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the API key you just need to append the parameter to the end of the query:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=[your_api_key]

If you click through the examples on their page, you'll see that they've updated their samples to include an API key: http://openweathermap.org/forecast5

Answer (score 0):

First [sign up for an API key here](http://openweathermap.org/appid)

Then add the API key to the end of the query:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=[your_api_key]
```